# zsh vs zsh-static

Tags: package-management, zsh

What is the difference between the [zsh](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/zsh) and [zsh-static](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/zsh-static) packages? Why are there two ZSH packages? Which one should I install if I want to use ZSH as my shell?

(Ubuntu version: 20.04 focal fossa).

Answer (score 1):

The `zsh-static` package is the statically-typed release of `zsh`. In plain English, this means that it does not require any dynamically loaded libraries to be present and will work even if the libraries used by `zsh` on your system are broken at some point in the future. For this reason, some people consider it "more robust" if you have a habit of breaking things so badly that you regularly reach for your Installation USB to repair an OS via a Live Session.

If you plan on using `zsh` like a "normal" person, then installing *just* the `zsh` package will be sufficient.